# Дождаться отпработки внутреннего промиса внутри then другого промиса

Tags: javascript

Есть примерно следующий код:

```js
var state = 'foo';

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(true)}).then((value) => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(true)}).then((value) => {
    state = 'foobar';
  }
  
  console.log(state);
})
```

То есть есть внешний промис, он выполняется, вызывается его then, а в нем другой промис, который тоже выполняется и вызывается его then в котором меняется глобальная переменная. Мне нужно, чтобы then внешнего промиса ждал пока выполнится then промиса внутри него и вывел в итоге 'foobar' в консоли.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы внешний промис ждал внутренний, надо возвращать его из внешнего:

```
var state = 'foo';

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(true)}).then((value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(true)}).then((value) => {
    return 'foobar';
  })
}).then(value => {
    state = value;
    console.log(state);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Такой вариант подходит?

```
let state = 'foo';

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(true)}).then((value) => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(true)}).then((value) => {
    state = 'foobar';
    console.log(state);
  }
})
```

Так же как вариант можно использовать `async function`:

```
let state = 'foo';

async function fn() {
  const res1 = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(true)});
  const res2 = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(true)});

  state = 'foobar';
  console.log(state);
}

fn()
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте еще 1 `then` во внутренний промис! тогда внешний будет ждать выполнения. Либо используйте await к примеру!

```js
var state = 'foo';

new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true)).then((value) => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true)).then(val => {
    state = 'foobar'
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(state);
  });
})
```

```js
var state = 'foo';

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve(true)}).then(async (value) => {
  await (async () => {state = 'foobar'})();  
  console.log(state);
})
```